# Find all possible values of an angle

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle with altitudes $BB_1$ and $CC_1$. Let $B_2$ and $C_2$ be the midpoints of $AC$ and $AB$, respectively. Find all possible values of $\angle BAC$ if $B_1C_2$ and $B_2C_1$ are perpendicular.

I have angle chased this problem many times, but I always keep getting $\angle BAC = 90^{\circ}$, contrary to the hypotesis of the problem that $ABC$ is an acute triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Add lines $BB_3$ and $CC_3$ such that $BB_3 // C_2B_1$ and $CC_3 // B_2C_1$.

[image]

By intercept theorem, $AB_1 = B_1B_3$ (and also $AC_1 = C_1C_3$)

Together with $BB_1$ is an altitude, we have $BA = BB_3$.

Similarly, $CA = CC_3$

Thus, the red marked angles are equal and $= 180^0 – 2\angle A$

By angle sum of triangle, $180^0 = \angle BKC + x + y$

$180^0 = \angle BKC + [\angle B – (180^0 – 2A)] + [\angle C – (180^0 – 2A)]$

:

$360^0 = \angle BKC + 3\angle A$

By corresponding angles between parallels, $\angle BKC = \angle B_1HC1 = \angle B_3KC_3 = 90^0$

∴ $\angle A$ has to be $90^0$

This means that requiring $\triangle ABC$ to be acute should be re-phrased as $\triangle ABC$ is non-obtuse.

Comment: How you draw these triangles? Which tools you used?

Comment: @BarzanHayati I am using GeoGebra.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, we can place the intersection of $B_1C_2$ and $B_2C_1$ at the origin of a Cartesian grid.

Further, since these are perpendicular, we can without loss of generality, choose to place $B_1$ at $(0,-a)$, $B_2$ at $(+b,0)$, $C_1$ at $(-d, 0)$, and $C_2$ at $(0,+c)$, iwth $a,b,c,d ? 0$. Then if you draw the diagram, $A$ liles on the intersection point of $B_1B_2$ and $C_1C_2$ (which will exist unless $(ad-bc = 0$).

The sine of the angle bewtween the lines define by  $B_1B_2$ and  $C_1C_2$ is given by the dot prodoct of the two difference vectors, over the product of magnitudes.  That is,
$$
\sin A = \frac{(b,a)\cdot (d,c)}{\sqrt{b^2+a^2}\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}
$$
Squaring, dividing the numerator by $abcd$, and letting $\frac{b}{a}=u$ and $\frac{c}{d}=v$  we get
$$
\sin^2 \angle BAC = \frac{uv + \frac{1}{uv}+2} {uv + \frac{1}{uv}+\frac{u}{v}+\frac{v}{u}}
$$
To explore the range of possible values of $\sin^2 \angle BAC$ we can  fixate on the case where  $uv=1$ (we will see that this gives us a full range of values).

When $u=1$ we see that $\sin^2 \angle BAC = 1$, and this is not allowed since the triangle is required to be acute.  But when $1=1+\epsilon$, for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$. $\sin^2 \angle BAC \approx 1 - \epsilon^2$ so we can come arbitrarily close to $90^\circ$.

When $u$ is large,  $$\sin^2 \angle BAC \approx \frac{4}{u^2}$$ which can be made arbitrarily small.

So the ranve of possible values of $\angle BAC$ is $(0^\circ, 90^\circ)$.

Comment: This is wrong. hehe